# Why do I need to call find() twice?

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program to parse a bunch of data, (you can get an example of the dataset itself here: https://explore.data.gov/Geography-and-Environment/Worldwide-M1-Earthquakes-Past-7-Days/7tag-iwnu).

The following class works perfectly fine, but **I am not sure why I need to call `matcher.find()` an extra time between each item in my `parseEarthquake()` method.  Why is that?  Is that a normal quirk I just have to deal with, or did I set it up my pattern/matcher incorrectly?**

The method takes a string containing one of the lines of data (for example, `nc,71958020,1,"Thursday, March 21, 2013 17:13:34 UTC",38.8367,-122.8298,1.4,2.60,28,"Northern California"`), and returns an earthquake object for the data.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.FieldPosition;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Earthquake {

    String src="xx";
    String eqid="00000000";
    short version;
    long dateTime;
    float lat, lon;
    float mag, dep;
    short nst;
    String region="Nowhere";

    private Earthquake(){
        date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }



    private static DecimalFormat 
            coords      = new DecimalFormat( "##0.0000" ),
            magnitude   = new DecimalFormat( "###0.0" ),
            depth       = new DecimalFormat( "###0.00" );
    private static SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("'\"'EEEE', 'MMMM' 'dd', 'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'zzz'\"'");


    // Src, Eqid, Version, Datetime, Lat, Lon, Magnitude, Depth, NST, Region;

    public static Earthquake parseEarthquake(String string){
        Earthquake result = new Earthquake();

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\".*?\")|([^,]*)").matcher(string);


        try {

                                matcher.find(); result.src = matcher.group();
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.eqid = matcher.group();
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.version = Short.parseShort(matcher.group());
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.dateTime = date.parse(matcher.group()).getTime();
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.lat = coords.parse(matcher.group()).floatValue();
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.lon = coords.parse(matcher.group()).floatValue();
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.mag = magnitude.parse(matcher.group()).floatValue();
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.dep = depth.parse(matcher.group()).floatValue();
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.nst = Short.parseShort(matcher.group());
                matcher.find(); matcher.find(); result.region = matcher.group();    

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

                            buf.append(src);
        buf.append(',');    buf.append(eqid);
        buf.append(',');    buf.append(version);
        buf.append(',');    date.format(dateTime, buf, new FieldPosition(0));
        buf.append(',');    coords.format(lat, buf, new FieldPosition(0));
        buf.append(',');    coords.format(lon, buf, new FieldPosition(0));
        buf.append(',');    magnitude.format(mag, buf, new FieldPosition(0));
        buf.append(',');    depth.format(dep, buf, new FieldPosition(0));
        buf.append(',');    buf.append(nst);
        buf.append(',');    buf.append('"'); buf.append(region); buf.append('"');

        return buf.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, as you may have guessed, I have a bunch of other stuff I plan to add to the class.  It is by no means completely finished.

Comment: You can remove most of the code (and bugs) if you'll use library for reading CSV file format.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev Is that library part of the java standard libraries?  I intend to end up using this as a part of a processing.org sketch, so that may prove extremely difficult if its not a standard library.

Comment: It's not part of standard Java. But you'll save much more time using well tested library vs writing your own.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because there are commas in the date portions of the entries

Comment: @IvanNevostruev Again, technical limitations are still limiting, despite the fact that I'd be better off without the limitations.  If I can't access the library in a processing.org sketch, then I really can't use it.

Comment: Then you can convert your data into some "easy to parse" format outside of processing.org. You can use standard java object serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `([^,]*)` to `([^,]+)`, as the former will always match - even it is only matching nothing.